# Agrupar conteúdo por mes e dia

Tags: php, mysql

Boa tarde Pessoal, estou com problema no agrupamento de conteúdo na seguinte estrutura:

Mes
Dia

Na query tenho duas tabelas, "agenda" e "usuario". Na tabela agenda tenho um campo do tipo "date" que "deveria" agrupar o conteúdo.

```
$data = date("Y-m-d");
$mes_atual = '';
$dia_atual = '';
$tbody = '';
$dados = Connection::select("Select agenda.id,u.nome as
     nome_pessoa,agenda.hora,agenda.compromisso,agenda.local,agenda.pessoa,
     agenda.data,DAYNAME(NOW()) AS dia, year(NOW()) AS ano,
     MONTHNAME(NOW()) AS mes from agenda inner join users u on 
    (agenda.pessoa = u.id) order by mes asc, dia asc, hora asc");

foreach ($dados as $reg) {
    if ($mes_atual != $reg['mes']) {
        $tbody.= '<tr><td colspan=4><h3>' . $reg['mes'] . '</h3></td></tr>';
        $mes_atual = $reg['mes'];
    }
    if ($dia_atual != $reg['dia']) {
        $tbody .= '<tr><td colspan=4><h5>' . $reg['dia'] . ', ' . $reg['dia'] . '</h5></td></tr>
<tr>
<td style="width:10%;"><b>Hora</b></td>
<td style="width:40%;"><b>Compromisso</b></td>
<td style="width:25%;"><b>Local</b></td>
<td style="width:25%;"><b>Pessoas</b></td>
</tr>';
        $dia_atual = $reg['dia'];
    }
    $tbody .= '
<tr>
<td style="width:10%;">' . $reg['hora'] . '</td>
<td style="width:40%;">' . $reg['compromisso'] . '</td>
<td style="width:25%;">' . $reg['local'] . '</td>
<td style="width:25%;">' . $reg['nome_pessoa'] . '</td>
</tr>                           
';
}
$html = str_replace('#TBODY#', $tbody, $html);
return $html;
```

O mais estranho é que se eu não relacionar as tabelas "agenda" e "usuario", os agrupamentos funcionam.

Comment: `DAYNAME(NOW()) AS dia, year(NOW()) AS ano,
     MONTHNAME(NOW()) AS mes` Que sentido tem pegar a data e hora atual na query? Não seria o nome do campo em vez do `NOW()` ? Achei meio estranha essa parte do seu código.

Comment: Nossa que vacilo, era bem esse o erro do código, acabou passando despercebido. Obrigado amigo.

Comment: Como você já resolveu o problema, estou votando para suspender sua pergunta como não sendo erro reprodutível, para evitar que o pessoal fique postando resposta achando que o problema está em aberto (isto não é uma punição nem uma crítica à sua postagem, apenas um mecanismo de organização do site). Mas se encontrar outros problemas no código, fique a vontade para fazer novas perguntas, estamos aqui pra ajudar. Se preferir, pode postar como resposta para sua própria pergunta como fez para resolver o problema, e marcá-la como aceita, assim também é um meio de deixar a postagem completa..

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer o que você quer no seu **Banco de Dados**:

```
Select 
  agenda.id,
  u.nome as  nome_pessoa,
  agenda.hora,
  agenda.compromisso,
  agenda.local,
  agenda.pessoa_id,
  agenda.data,
  DAYNAME(NOW()) AS dia, year(NOW()) AS ano, MONTHNAME(NOW()) AS mes 
FROM 
    agenda  inner join users u on (agenda.pessoa_id = u.id) 
    order by agenda.data asc, agenda.hora asc
```

Se você observar só mudei a última linha, agora meu ponto de vista usaria a estrutura abaixo:

```
SELECT
    USER.nome,
    AGENDA.id,
    AGENDA.hora,
    AGENDA.compromisso,
    AGENDA.local,
    AGENDA.pessoa_id,
    AGENDA.data
FROM 
    agenda as AGENDA,
    users as USER
ORDER BY 
    AGENDA.data ASC,
    AGENDA.hora ASC
```

No **PHP** você trabalha as funções de detecção de Mês e Dia e ainda de quebra consegue fazer a tradução para a linguagem que você definir:

```
<?php
   #garante a traducao
   setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR');
   #garante que vai ficar setado a data correta de acordo com a timezone
   date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
   #http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strftime.php
   $dia = strftime("%A");
   $mes = strftime("%B");
   echo "Hoje é <b>$dia</b> do mês de <b>$mes</b>";
?>
```

Dá uma pesquisada melhor, usar as ferramentas certas, no fim das contas vale a pena.